# How do I iterate through a pandas data frame to return a different column's value based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Lets say I have a table:

| tableName | parentPartitionKey | parentTableName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User | entityId | Entity |
| Employee | entityId | Entity |
| Customer | entityId | Entity |
| CreditType | creditId | Credit |
| Entity | None | None |

Essentially, for each table I want to look for the parentTable’s partition key value. For example, table User has a parent table ‘Entity’. I want to return the Entity’s partition key value. How do I iterate through the data frame to find every table’s parentPartitionKey?

I tried using a np.where but this didn’t work. I am not trying to merge this data frame.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["parentPartitionKey"].where(row["parentTableName"] == row["tableName”])))
```

Comment: What do you want as the output?

Comment: probably you should consider `df.set_index('tableName').drop('parentTableName', 1).to_dict()['parentPartitionKey']`

Comment: `df['parentTableName'].map(df.set_index('tableName')['parentPartitionKey'])`

Comment: I want it to return a single value for every row, so this could return a list.

Comment: These don't allow me to get a single value.

Comment: "I want to return the Entity’s partition key value" if your table is representative of a database, your entity table wouldn't have any referenced key value in there. Add the primary key of each table to the mix and maybe we have something.